# ADAL SQL Server TokenCache save issue

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I am trying to implement SQL Server caching for ADAL tokens following the approach over [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-multitenant-openidconnect/blob/master/TodoListWebApp/DAL/EFADALTokenCache.cs). The database instance is an Azure SQL DB.

In order to implement, I have created the necessary table with specified columns in SQL Server i.e. entryId (int), webUserUniqueId (nvarchar(max)), cacheBits(varbinary(max)) and lastWrite. While saving the changes to the cache after a token has been generated, an event "AfterAccessNotification" is triggered to update the database. However, I am getting the exception on SaveChanges - "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated.The statement has been terminated."

What am I missing here?.

Comment: Based on the error message, it seems that there is a column is less than what you are trying to insert. To arrow down this issue, I suggest that you track the SQL stamens the code actually execute in the database and to check whether the issue is caused by this reason.

Comment: @FeiXue - The issue was resolved couple of weeks back when I had posted. But here is what turned out to be an issue - I was using The Visual Studio 2017's integration with Sql server to manage the schema changes and it appears like those changes were not getting committed, although I didn't receive any error. I used the SQL Management Studio to make my schema changes and all turned out to be fine.